# Daily Unique Actions/Monthly Unique Actions by Country? ex: DAU/MAU

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas, amazon-redshift

Maybe you guys can help me out with something. I made two queries to track the unique daily number of actions and the monthly unique number of actions. However I now want to look at these numbers for different regions but am having issues with it. I know it will involve some subqueries that I haven't completely wrapped my head around.

A bit about what I'm working with, I'm using Postgres to query before playing around in pandas/python or R. I'm pretty confident this can be done much quicker with just a SQL query.

I have an events table something like the following:

```
userid,    date,    event,      item
1,         1/1/15   like        A
2,         1/1/15   view        A
3,         1/1/15   view        B
2,         1/1/15   purchase    A
1,         1/1/15   view        B
```

To compute the Daily Views/Monthly Views I currently do something like the following:

```
daily_views = """
SELECT date(events.date) as daily_date, count(distinct events.userid) as daily_user 
FROM 
events
WHERE
date(events.date) between '2014-11-01' and '2015-01-31' AND
events.event LIKE '%%VIEW%%'
GROUP BY
date(events.date)"""
```

and Monthly

```
Monthly_Views = """
SELECT daily_date, daily_user, count(distinct events.userid) AS monthly_views
FROM
({daily_views})
LEFT OUT JOIN events ON events.date BETWEEN daily_date - INTERVAL '30 days' AND daily_date
WHERE events.event LIKE '%%LOGIN%%'
GROUP BY daily_date, daily_user
ORDER BY daily_date ASC""".format(daily_views=daily_views)
```

which returns me a table:

date, daily_user, monthly_user

Now to include region of interest, I have another table called users_data:

```
userid, country, ...
1,      a
2,      b
3,      a
4,      a
```

I apparently went brain dead when I was thinking about this so to include language, I did a really roundabout way of doing it by first joining users_data on events:

```
SELECT date(events.date), count(distinct events.userid) number_of_users, users_data.country
FROM events
JOIN users_data 
ON
users_data.userid = events.userid
WHERE date(events.dateday) > '2014-11-20' and date(events.dateday) < '2014-11-22'
AND trackevents.event LIKE '%%%%VIEW%%%%'
GROUP BY 
date(events.dateday), users_data.country
ORDER BY
date(events.date)
```

Likewise I think computed this over the a month range:

```
SELECT count(distinct events.userid) number_of_users, users_data.country
from events 
JOIN users_data 
ON
users_data.userid = events.userid
WHERE date(events.dateday) > '2014-10-01' and date(events.dateday) < '2014-11-01'
AND events.event LIKE '%%VIEW%%'
GROUP BY 
users_data.country
```

Which then I had to sort used Pandas to print out for a particular country of interest.

While this allowed me to get my answer, it was incredible stupid and time consuming. I know there is a better way to get there, but I'm a little stumped right now. Basically I would like to get something similar to the first either for a specified language or by language:

```
date,        daily, monthly, country
2014-11-01,  1239,  5123,    US 
2014-11-01,  439,   1123,    CA
2014-11-02,  1439,  5653,    US
2014-11-01,  402,   1224,    CA
```

I would prefer a SQL statement but Pandas if need be. Also if you notice, if there is a nice way to do the date like the first one. I'm still learning SQL and slightly beyond me right now to do quickly.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Not related to your question, but not all months have 30 days.

Comment: That's true Dan! However the standard practice for monthly metrics such as MAU is not to look over the previous month, but the previously thirty days.  That way we can get a value for any day of interest.